# Validate two text fields together in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare two text fields to make sure that the summation of two values should be equal to 100. I couldn't find any java script for this matter.

Comment: Post what you allready have please. And explain what you don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You din't explained your problem well, but I think this is what you want:

```
<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text">
<button onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>

function onClick(){
var first = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
var second = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
var sum = first + second;
if (sum == 100)
{
    ...//Your code here...
}

}
```

Please tell me if this din't work for you.